# How to replace the default click event by a double click event for grid row selection in ExtJS

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS 6.2.0. I have a standard grid. The grid's selection model, and all of it's related functions like the highlighting of grid rows, is by default triggered by the single click event.
I would like to keep all of the selection model's functionality, but driven by a double click event instead.
I was thinking along the line of killing the default single click event listener, and introducing a dedicated double click event listener. But I can't find any handle on this default event listener.
Any suggestions?

Comment: There isn't options for it. You need to override base functions.

Comment: @norbeq: I was afraid of that. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score -1):

Use clicksToEdit property in grid plugins as follow

```
Ext.define('Test.MyGrid', {
extend:'Ext.grid.Panel',
store: store,
xtype:'myGrid',
 plugins: {
    rowediting: {
        clicksToEdit: 2,
        autoCancel: false
    }
},
columns: [
    { text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name',editor:{
                allowBlank: false
        } },
    { text: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
    { text: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
]

});
```

Check working example https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ma9

Comment: There was a problem with the selection highlight, not the plugin's way of editing the record.

Comment: @Moataz: I agree with norbeq, there is now row editing involved. Nice feature though.