# How to prevent text selection in an ExtJS grid cell from firing the onclick event handler and have the grid row (de-)selected as a result

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS 6.2.0. I have a standard grid. In some of the grid cells I have text that a user is able to select (for copy-paste purposes).
However, upon selection of that text (through mousedown-mouseup), also the onclick event handler of that row is fired, causing in my case the (de-)selection of that grid row.
I am looking for a way to make these text selections, but without triggering the onclick event handler.
I was thinking along the line of killing the default single click event listener, and introducing a dedicated double click event listener, but that route hasn't led to a simple solution so far.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace the default click event by a double click event for grid row selection in ExtJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557779/how-to-replace-the-default-click-event-by-a-double-click-event-for-grid-row-sele)

Comment: @Moataz: I'm afraid it does not. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change `selectionModel` to `Ext.selection.CheckboxModel` and set `enableTextSelection` in `viewConfig`.

```
selModel: {
    type: 'checkboxmodel',
    checkOnly: true
},
viewConfig: {
    enableTextSelection: true
}
```

Example : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/35o5

Comment: This comes very close to what I need, especially when you add the selModel's configs mode:'single' and allowDeselect:true.
But the simple row selection by single click or just scrolling down through the grid by keyboard arrow, which I got used to, gets lost.

Comment: Maybe you should change `enableKeyNav`and `toggleOnClick` options.